# VB 2010 - Stop a loop with a button

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am using VB 2010 , I have a loop that takes something like 5 minutes until it's finish.
I want to allow the user the option to stop it in the middle or whenever they want.
There's a button which starts the loop , and after I click it the loop starts running and the button is sort of "stuck".
I saw something called "background work" in the VB Toolbox, can it be a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your loop in separate thread and set a flag  which directs the action of the loop . Keep polling for this flag to see whether user wants to stop the thread inside the loop on thread . See [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think background worker would work, but a very simple solution if to create a boolean variable (visible in scope to your stop button and the logic loop) that controls stopping inside your loop. Your stop button would set the variable to true and the next time that code is hit, it would stop. you may need an application.doevents inside your loop at the end to allow the button's event to fire. This is not an ideal way, but is certainly simple.